# Find the values of Tangent line that isn't given

Tags: derivatives

I'm going through a review for an upcoming exam and this has me stumped:

The line tangent to $y=f(x)$ at $x=3$ passes through the points $(0,10)$ and $(10,30)$.
Find the values of $f(3)$ and $f'(3)$.

I tried basic formatting for the functions, but the preview window showed \int as not working. 
f' is indicating the first derivative.

Comment: Can you find the equation of the tangent line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation of tangent is $y=2x+10$, so $f'(3)=2$. So $f(3)=16$.

To do this, note that the tangent line intersects the $y$-axis at 10. And a quick computation of the gradient gives you $\frac{30-10}{10-0}=2$. And you should be home from there.

Comment: This worked great for me. I must've had a brain fart because once I saw it, it all came flooding back.

Comment: No problem, all the best for your exam.